# Error message while using Pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, julia

PyPlot does not function anymore. It comes up with this error message:

**This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.**

I reinstalled anything from scratch (all programs are 'freshly' downloaded):
-Julia 
-Atom
-Anaconda (including Matplotlib 2.0)

But I get always the same error message.
Any hint are appreciated.

Comment: show the code that generated this message. Saying "it doesn't work" is very difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: This may be the issue which was just fixed on master, but it's hard to tell since you didn't give much of an error message. https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyPlot.jl/issues/278

Comment: @PaulH"it doesn't work" means no plot is generated as it does before. Instead the error message pops up.

Comment: @Chris Rackauckas Thank you for the hint: for the time being the following works fine: ENV["MPLBACKEND"]="qt4agg"
using PyPlot

Comment: Did you find a solution?